# williams fractal insted of high and low

Tags: fractals

I wrote below code in pine script in tradingview for high and low weekly candles , and now I want you help me to bring Williams fractal from weekly to daily time frame .

```
//@version=5
indicator("line1" , overlay =true)
s = request.security("Kucoin:BTCUSDT", "W", high) // 1 Day
t = request.security("Kucoin:BTCUSDT", "W", low ) // 1 Day
plot(s)
plot(t)
```

Comment: What code/language is that? Please [edit] your question to edit the tags list accordingly.